# Restrict whole system on certain cores except a few process?

Tags: linux, centos

Hi I am running some latency sensitive program on a Linux machine (more specifically, CentOS 6), and I don't want the threads of the process being preempted.  So in my plan, the first step is to set cpu affinity of the threads so that threads are running on separate cores, so they don't preempt each other.  Then the second step is to make sure other processes in the system not running on these cores.

So my question is: is it possible to restrict the whole system running on certain cores, except this process? This should apply to any newly created processes in the future.

Comment: You're probably going about this the wrong way. The solution is probably just to give the latency-sensitive threads absolute priority rather than waste cores when there's no latency-sensitive work to be done. Tell us more about what the latency sensitive threads do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cgroups which are available on CentOS 6 have a cpuset subsystem that allows you to choose which process runs on which set of CPU.
With the cpuset subsytem, you can create a cpuset with just one CPU, put all currently running processes in that cpuset, that is "restrict the whole system running on certain cores" as you stated in your question. Then, you can create another cpuset with the remaining CPUs, launch the threaded process and put the process in the newly created cpuset.

Cgroups and cpuset are managed entirely with mount, mkdir and echo commands.

There is also the [cset](https://code.google.com/p/cpuset/) utility which provides higher level functions to cpuset (with mkdir / echo , you need to move each process with a for loop in a cpuset).